# UICollectionView indexPathsForVisibleItems order

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I use UICollectionView to display the content in column 2. I need to track changes in the visible cells.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    NSArray* visibleCellIndex = collectionViewCatalog.indexPathsForVisibleItems;

    NSIndexPath* newFirstVisibleCell = [visibleCellIndex firstObject];
    NSIndexPath* newLastVisibleCell = [visibleCellIndex lastObject];
    NSLog(@"Visible cells [ %i ; %i]",newFirstVisibleCell.row,newLastVisibleCell.row);
}
```

Log: `Visible cells [ 0 ; 3]`, but sometimes crash order `Visible cells [ 5 ; 4]` or `Visible cells [ 12 ; 11]`
Log indexPathsForVisibleItems for cells [ 5 ; 4]:

```
(
    "<NSIndexPath: 0x1653bb90> {length = 2, path = 0 - 5}",
    "<NSIndexPath: 0x1655ab10> {length = 2, path = 0 - 2}",
    "<NSIndexPath: 0x1655aa80> {length = 2, path = 0 - 3}",
    "<NSIndexPath: 0x16539680> {length = 2, path = 0 - 4}"
)
```

After this (Visible cells [ 5 ; 4]) next log info: `Visible cells [ 6 ; 9]` no log from 5 to 9 cells

I have only 20 cells. Why crash order indexPaths in array indexPathsForVisibleItems?

Comment: I’m trying really hard but I can’t understand this sentence: "Why crash order indexPaths in array indexPathsForVisibleItems?"

Comment: @user2828120, you should write an answer and put a checkmark.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the NSIndexPath header:

```
// comparison support
- (NSComparisonResult)compare:(NSIndexPath *)otherObject; // sorting an array of indexPaths using this comparison results in an array representing nodes in depth-first traversal order
```

You could therefore do:

```
NSArray *sortedVisibleItems = [[collectionViewCatalog indexPathsForVisibleItems] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

Answer (score 3):

```
NSArray *sortedIndexPaths = [visibleCellIndex sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
            NSIndexPath *path1 = (NSIndexPath *)obj1;
            NSIndexPath *path2 = (NSIndexPath *)obj2;
            return [path1 compare:path2];
        }];
```